# Use variable in JSON notation

Tags: javascript, json

I have a variable that I want to use to get a Json property. I can't figure out how, if even possible.

```
var variablename='netherlands';
alert(jsonObjectName.variablename[0].capital);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I follow you, you want to do this:

```
alert(jsonObjectName[variableName].capital);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var variablename='netherlands';
alert(jsonObjectName[variablename].capital);
```